Is electron elementary from a representation theory point of view?
From what I've understood, particles correspond to irreducible representations of Poincaré group on one particle state of the Fock space. To know which kind of particle can be realized by a given representation of Poincaré group on fields we need to see which irreducible representations of SO(3) (for massive particles) or of ISO(2) (for massless particles) corresponds to it. Now, I don't see how electrons can fit into this scheme, since we use (1/2, 0) + (0, 1/2) representation, which is reducible, to describe them. I think my problem is that I don't know what is (if any) the irreducible representation of SO(3) that corresponds to the direct sum of these two irreducible representations.

How do I know which particle does this representation give?
Should I think of the particle associated to this representation (aka electron) as the composition of the two fermions corresponding to Weyl spinors?
Does this mean that electrons are not elementary particles?


If instead of the part of Lorentz  connected to the identity you include as well parity,  then the Dirac fields are in fact irreps. Conversely, on theories that break parity like the (ew-sector of the) standard model is preferable to treat the right-handed  and left-handed field as separate irreps of Sl(2,c), as that have generically diffèrent interactions. That said, the electron and positrons, as states, are considered elementary as they fit the into renornalizable  theory experimentally verified up to ~few tens of TeV so that any compositeness, if any, must be hide at those scales or higher

Thanks for the answer! I still have some doubts: in the first kind of theories that you mention, what is the little group associated to the direct sum of (1/2,0) and (0,1/2)? Intuitively I think it's SO(3) with j=1/2 (for massive particles), but I don't know how to prove it. If I have an irrep (n,m) of Poincaré group I know that the possible particles have spin j=|n-m|,..., n+m, but here I don't know what to do. In the second kind of theories, where the Weyl spinors are treated as fundamental, is it correct to say that technically electrons are composite particles?

There is a bit of confusion here, the fields are classified by irreps of Lorentz (or more correctly of SL(2,C) ) whereas the states are classified by irreps of Poincaré (or more correctly the semi direct product of translations and SL(2,C))  possibly extended by discrete transformations.  Anyway, coming to your question: the massive little group is a subgroup of Poincaré (or its discrete extensions) that leave eg $(m,0,0,0)$ invariant. In a parity invariant theory is therefore $O(3)$ since parity leave that reference vector invariant too

I think that it is better to think of the electron as a "mix" of two particles, the left-handed and the right-handed electrons, $e_L$ and $e_R$. These particles respectively correspond to the irreps $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$. These two are mixed by the mass term of the Dirac Lagrangian, which is
$$
m \bar{e} e \equiv m \left(e_L^\dagger e_R + e_R^\dagger e_L \right),
$$
which more generally mixes the left- and right-handed Weyl spinors that form any Dirac spinor.
As far as we know, the electron doesn't have an inner structure, so we consider it an elementary particle. This is proved through scattering experiments. This means that we shoot something at an electron, and look at how "it bounces off". We later compare the experimental result to the theoretical predictions of how it should "bounce off" considering that it isfundamental or that it has a substructure.

As a side note, in the electroweak theory, this gets another twist, as it turns out that $e_L$ alone isn't a field. Indeed, we have that the left-handed electron is paired with the left-handed neutrino into the field
$$
\left( e_L\,\,\nu_L \right)
$$
which is charged under the fundamental representation of a $SU(2)$ gauge group. Nevertheless, we can still recover at "low" energies our beloved electron, which doesn't have structure.
